# What will be an optimal method to Store Multiple Pandas DataFrames Together

Tags: python, pandas

I want to store multiple pandas dataframe in some sort of iterable collection, as in a list or dictionary.

However, each of my dataframes countain thousands of rows and hundreds of columns. Until now I have been storing them in a list. I want to know if it is an optimal method to store the dataframes in a list? If not is there another method to do so?

I am not sure if the code for storage is needed in this situation but here it is:

```
#df_lst is the list used to store the dataframes
for i in (my_files):
    df_lst.append(pd.read_excel(i))
```

Comment: What are you dataframe used for, and what the problem you are facing with the actual list strategy? If you have no problem, the list (or a dict) does the job. 

A dict may be more efficient (thanks to its indexing) though. 

Otherwise, describe the problem (time / memory consumption, etc?)

Comment: I am worried that my data frames will eventually be too big for the list and I would loose some data, while loading.
It does take a lot longer to load and store these dataframes, howevere, that is not a major issue for me

Answer (score 0):

To manage dataframes that exceed memory size, you can use Dask dataframes: https://www.dask.org/get-started